# Evalulating $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ (\frac{5}{13})^n \right\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How do I evaluate:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ \left(\frac{5}{13}\right)^n \right\}$$

using mathematical techniques?  I wrote a line of Powershell to do it:

```
@(1..100) | % { [Math]::Pow(5/13, $_) } | Measure-Object -Sum
```

and the answer is $0.625$, but how do I do it with maths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{13}\right)^n$$

Then we have

$$S - \frac{5}{13}S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{13}\right)^n - \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{13}\right)^n$$
Note that this works because $\left(\frac{5}{13}\right)^n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. The base of the exponential expression has to have an absolute value $ < 1$, for the series to converge. It won't work for things like $2^n$, or $(-1.1)^n$.

Continuing, we have:
$$\frac{8}{13}S = \frac{5}{13}$$
$$S = \frac{5}{8}$$

We can, using the same approach, generalize (for $|x| < 1$) this to derive the summation of a convergent infinite geometric series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Comment: @YiyuanLee: The infinite series can't be treated as finite series. Suppose one use the same trick with $S= 1+2+4+8\ldots$, $2S = 2+4+8\ldots$ so $2S-S=-1$, so $S=-1$, one gets a nonsensical result. I think we need to be more specific when  we can trust in this trick.

Comment: Yes indeed, I'll add in the condition for which this works. Thanks!

Comment: I like all three answers.  I take it that if we generalize your notation, we get the "formula of summation of Infinite Geometric Series", as noted by jordix and lab (for fractions)?

Comment: @TahirHassan Yes, this is essentially a derivation for the summation of an infinite geometric series.

Answer (score 5):

This is a geometric series:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$, or

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}$.

These expressions are valid for $|x| < 1$, in particular for $x = \frac{5}{13}$, which is your case.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series) of summation of Infinite Geometric Series, the sum will be $$\frac{\dfrac5{13}}{1-\dfrac5{13}}=\frac5{13-5}$$

Here the common ratio is $\displaystyle\frac5{13}$

Comment: common "ratio" did you mean sum?

Comment: @Sabyasachi, Please go through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: then shouldn't the common ratio be $\frac5{13}$?. the *sum* is $\frac58$. I know what a geometric series is.

Comment: @Sabyasachi, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: yeah, it's okay. :)